# How i can use Poppler-QML-plugin in my application?

Tags: qt, qml, poppler

Hello guys i have found into this repository

https://github.com/dept2/Poppler-QML-plugin

a qml plugin for show a pdf file into a qml file, but i don't know how i can use it someone can help me?

In ubuntu 18.04 version i have found this plugin with command line sudo apt-cache search poppler and i have installed the package but i have the same problem , how i can use it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do I have to import something into the .pro file?

Comment: Maybe it is not installed( the package is qtdeclarative5-poppler1.0 - Poppler QML plugin)  because i have this error "QML module not found". If i want manually install the files of the plugin that i have found into repository how i can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 possible methods:

### 1. Compile and install the plugin:

To install this package I must install the plugin for it first download the project, open a terminal in the project directory and execute the following:

```
qmake
make
sudo make install
```

Then in the .qml import the module, the `Poppler` item provides an `imageProvider` so you should use an Image as I show below:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import org.docviewer.poppler 1.0 // <--- import
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3

Window {
    id: win
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Poppler Example")

    function urlToPath(urlString) {
        var s
        if (urlString.startsWith("file:///")) {
            var k = urlString.charAt(9) === ':' ? 8 : 7
            s = urlString.substring(k)
        } else {
            s = urlString
        }
        return decodeURIComponent(s);
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title: "Please choose a file"
        folder: shortcuts.home
        nameFilters: ["PDF files (*.pdf)", "All files (*)"]
        onAccepted: timer.running = true
        Component.onCompleted: visible = true
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 100; repeat: false
        onTriggered: {
            poppler.path = urlToPath(""+fileDialog.fileUrl)
            view.focus = true
        }
    }

    Poppler{
        id: poppler
    }

    ListView{
        id: view
        height: parent.height
        width: 100
        model: poppler.numPages
        delegate:  Image{
            id: image
            width: parent.width
            source: poppler.loaded? "image://poppler/page/" + (modelData+1): ""
            sourceSize.width: width
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    image.ListView.view.currentIndex = index
                    image.ListView.view.focus = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Flickable {
        height: parent.height
        anchors.left: view.right
        anchors.right: parent.right
        contentWidth: bigImage.width;
        contentHeight: bigImage.height
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        Image{
            id: bigImage
            sourceSize.width: win.width - view.width
            source: (poppler.loaded && view.currentIndex >= 0)?  "image://poppler/page/"+(view.currentIndex+1): ""
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### 2. Create .pri

I have created a .pri that is a simple way to attach the files to the project:

poppler-qml.pri:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

SOURCES += \
    $$PWD/pdfModel.cpp \
    $$PWD/pageImageProvider.cpp

HEADERS += \
    $$PWD/pdfModel.h \
    $$PWD/pageImageProvider.h


unix|win32: LIBS += -lpoppler-qt5
```

The files must have the following structure:

```
poppler-qml
    ├── pageImageProvider.cpp
    ├── pageImageProvider.h
    ├── pdfModel.cpp
    ├── pdfModel.h
    └── poppler-qml.pri
```

And then add it to your .pro:

```
...
include(poppler-qml/poppler-qml.pri)
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <pdfModel.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("POPPLERPLUGIN_DEBUG", "1"); /// enable debug
    qmlRegisterType<PdfModel>("org.docviewer.poppler", 1, 0, "Poppler");
    ...
```

For example in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/52843694) you can find an example.

**Note:**

The initial code of the plugin has a bug because if it asks for a page that does not exist the application should return a null QImage but as it does not do the verification the application can be broken

```
page = document->page(numPage -1);
if(!page)
    return result;
```